# using Windows.Services.Maps not available for some reason

Tags: c#, silverlight, windows-phone-8.1, windows-phone

I am trying to use `Windows.Services.Maps` in a windows phone 8.1 silverlight app but the namespace doesn't seem to exist in the current context.  I've tried searching for it in the references but can't find it.  Has it been discontinued or is it just unavailable in the type of project I am doing?
This is for an app that gets a current address from gps coordinates.

Answer (score 0):

As you can see [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows.services.maps.mapservice.aspx) the Windows.Services.Maps namespace is only available in Windows Runtime apps.

See [this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dn818495.aspx) article for more techniques you can use in a regular Windows Phone Silverlight applications to get a location based on an address.